# Regression with related coefficients

Tags: regression, estimation, regression-coefficients, offset

I've worked out that some physical process has the form $y = ax_1 + (1-a)x_2$, and would like to perform regression to find $a$. I thought about multiple regression of $y$ on $x_1$ and $x_2$ and hoping the coefficients sum to 1, but I guess this isn't guaranteed.

A second way is to rearrange to find $y = a(x_1 - x_2) + x_2$, then by regressing $y-x_2$ on $x_1 - x_2$ you can find the slope $a$. Does anyone have any ideas on which is the correct method?

Comment: Your second proposal is the (practical) way to go! If you use R, you also have the concept of offset(), which you can use to fix the parameter of $x_2$ to be 1. In linear regression you can as well subtract it from $y$, but in non-linear situations that is not so direct ...

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I believe $y$ and $\{x\}$ are poisson distributed, which implies $y-x_2$ is skellam distributed, which I'm guessing will be difficult for regression. I'll try regression forcing one coefficient to 1 and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

In the comments there is additional information that $y$ is poisson distributed, indicating poisson regression. It is also said that $x_2$ has a poisson distribution, but in general distribution of predictors is irrelevant for regression, since regression analysis is *conditional on* the regressors.

Starting with the rearrangement $ y = a(x_1 - x_2) + x_2$, the second term $x_2$ is a term with known coefficient, in this case 1. Such a term with known coefficient of 1 is known as an *offset*, so in R we could do:

```
mod1  <- glm( y ~ I(x1-x2)+offset(x2), family=poisson, data=yourdataframe)
summary(mod1)
```

and more complicated models could be built from there.